# OpenGL es: best way to "cull" in the vertex shader

Tags: vertex-shader

I have some boolean logic in the vertex shader to determine whether vertices should be culled or not (each vertex has a groupID and i pass a cullingMask as a uniform to the shader). That logic is guaranteed to return the same result for all vertices of a primitive.

What's the best way to cull those primitives at that stage? just setting clip position of all these vertices to 0,0,0,0 ? or maybe to 1,1,1,1 (so that it falls outside the clip volume) ?

Or is there a better way alltogether?

In particular, I don't want these primitives to end up in any bins after the binning stage of GPUs with tiled renderer.

Comment: scale your model down to 0

Comment: @Raildex so return [0,0,0,1] from the vertex shader for the primitives that I want to cull?

Comment: that should work, yes.

Although i wonder why you render the vertices in the first place. Why don't you just cull them on the cpu?

Comment: @Raildex because I'm CPU limited

Comment: Alternatively set `gl_Position` to NaN.

Comment: @YakovGalka does that yield defined behavior?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann AFAIK GLSL is specified to be able to consume NaNs, even if it's not required to generate them. Nothing in the spec says that NaN in `gl_Position` would cull the primitive, but that's what all implementations I tested do -- and I cannot imagine what else would happen.